# How to force key types in TypeScript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make an object interface which force to use string as keys, but TypeScript compiler pass codes even if it had a number type as a key. Why?

For example,

```
interface PriceI {
    [key:string]:number;
}

var coursePrice: PriceI = {};
coursePrice["Orange"] = 100;
coursePrice["Apple"] = 200;
coursePrice[3]=200;    // It should be compile error, but it pass
coursePrice[true]=300; // It's compile error
```

Comment: The static typing in typescript is a compromise between the highly dynamic nature of javascript and the rigid type-enforcement in most strongly typed languages. I myself would prefer a stricter TS, but the designers are afraid to scare away people coming from JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

> There are two types of supported index signatures: string and number. It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer. This is because when indexing with a `number`, JavaScript will actually convert that to a `string` before indexing into an object. That means that indexing with `100` (a `number`) is the same thing as indexing with `"100"` (a `string`), so the two need to be consistent.

In your example, TypeScript considers that `coursePrice[3] = 200;` is equivalent to `coursePrice["3"] = 200;`.